# IloBoolVarArray syntax help needed

Tags: c++, cplex

i am trying to solve LP using CPLEX in C++. i am little bit confused with the syntax. here is my problem. i have defined the integer constant like this:

```
const int NumberOfSemesters = 10
```

and defined one decision variable in CPLEX like this:

```
IloBoolVarArray Y(env, NumberOfSemesters); // equals to 1 if student 
                                          //takes at least one course in semster s
```

this decision variable output will be arrays of 1 and 0(i.e: [0,0,1,0,0,1])

then i defined one constraint such that:

```
//Constraint 1:student has no leave of absence     
for (ss = 0; ss < NumberOfSemesters; ss++) {
    mod.add(Y[ss + 1] <= Y[ss]);
}
```

now when i run the code i get this error which i do not underestand,
[image]

i think the way i defined decision variable is wrong.i read the IBM website for IloBoolVarArray but the syntax confused me. any idea? or is anyone knows a source for learning CPLEX syntax in C++ with examples other than IBM website?

Answer (score 2):

In C++ the array are indexed by 0. So a N element array is accessible via
`arr[0]` to `arr[N-1]`.
When you write:

```
for (ss = 0; ss < NumSem; s++) {
  mod.add(Y[ss+1] <= Y[ss]);
}
```

You are accessing the (N+1)th element in the array (since `ss` will be `(NumSem - 1)`, thus `ss+1` is `NumSem`) and this is an access violation.

You have to limit the access within the bounds of the array.